# How to read images in a preset folder and display it on an image area using Livecode?

Tags: slideshow, livecode

How to read images in a preset folder and display it on an image area using Livecode?

I have read through many Livecode sites but could not find an example.

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

create a button  "butn" and image area "imag"
then put this code in that button.

```
repeat with i =0 to the number of images in url "~/your/folder/path"
put it into image "imag"
wait 2 sec
end repeat
```

I should work, but i don't checked. if not, keep this logic in your mind and try it yourself.

all the best.